# How to workaround "the input device is not a TTY" when using grunt-shell to invoke a script that calls docker run?

Tags: docker, gruntjs, tty, grunt-shell

When issuing `grunt shell:test`, I'm getting warning "the input device is not a TTY" & don't want to have to use `-f`:

```
$ grunt shell:test
Running "shell:test" (shell) task
the input device is not a TTY
Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c ./run.sh npm test
the input device is not a TTY
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Here's the `Gruntfile.js` command:

```
shell: {
  test: {
    command: './run.sh npm test'
  }
```

Here's `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# should use the latest available image to validate, but not LATEST
if [ -f .env ]; then
  RUN_ENV_FILE='--env-file .env'
fi
docker run $RUN_ENV_FILE -it --rm --user node -v "$PWD":/app -w /app yaktor/node:0.39.0 $@
```

Here's the relevant `package.json` `scripts` with command `test`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --color=true -R spec test/*.test.js && npm run lint"
}
```

How can I get `grunt` to make `docker` happy with a TTY?  Executing `./run.sh npm test` outside of grunt works fine:

```
$ ./run.sh npm test

> yaktor@0.59.2-pre.0 test /app
> mocha --color=true -R spec test/*.test.js && npm run lint


[snip]

  105 passing (3s)


> yaktor@0.59.2-pre.0 lint /app
> standard --verbose
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Remove the `-t` from the docker run command:

```
docker run $RUN_ENV_FILE -i --rm --user node -v "$PWD":/app -w /app yaktor/node:0.39.0 $@
```

The `-t` tells docker to configure the tty, which won't work if you don't have a tty and try to attach to the container (default when you don't do a `-d`).

Answer (score 8):

This solved an annoying issue for me. The script had these lines:

```
docker exec **-it**  $( docker ps | grep mysql | cut -d' ' -f1)  mysql --user= ..... > /var/tmp/temp.file
mutt -s "File is here" someone@somewhere.com < /var/tmp/temp.file
```

The script would run great if run directly and the mail would come with the correct output. However, when run from `cron`, (`crontab -e`) the mail would come with no content. Tried many things around permissions and shells and paths etc. However no joy!

Finally found this:

```
*/20 * * * * scriptblah.sh > $HOME/cron.log 2>&1
```

And on that `cron.log` file found this output:

> the input device is not a TTY

Search led me here. And after I removed the `-t`, it's working great now!

```
docker exec **-i**  $( docker ps | grep mysql | cut -d' ' -f1)  mysql --user= ..... > /var/tmp/temp.file
```