# Cannot run external tool with argument

Tags: linux, eclipse, bash, shell

I am trying to configure Eclipse under linux to run my .sh script with arguments. I am using External tools configuration to this end. I am able to run my script, but as soon as I add an argument i receive a message `the input device is not a TTY` in the console and the script is not run. This is my config:

[image]

What could be the case of this? I would appreciate all help.

Edit: this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
EDISON_DEVICE="root@192.168.1.202:/tmp"
WORK_DIR=$(pwd)

CLEAN=false
BUILD=false
TEST=false
CREATE_DOC=false
UPLOAD=false

#tabs 30
if [ $# -eq 0 ] 
then
   echo -e "Options:\n-c, --clean \tClean project\n-b, --build\tBuild project\n-d, --doc\t Create documentation\n-u, --upload\tUpload project to Edison device\n-e, --edison string\tEdison device ip (need to copy output)"
fi

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
key="$1"

case $key in
    --help)
    echo -e "Options:\n-c, --clean \tClean project\n-b, --build\tBuild project\n-d, --doc\t Create documentation\n-u, --upload\tUpload project to Edison device\n-e, --edison string\tEdison device ip (need to copy output)"
    exit
    ;;
    -c|--clean)
    CLEAN=true
    ;;
    -b|--build)
    BUILD=true
    ;;
    -t|--test)
    TEST=true
    ;;
    -d|--doc)
    CREATE_DOC=true
    ;;
    -u|--upload)
    UPLOAD=true
    ;;
    -e|--edison)
    EDISON_DEVICE="$2"
    shift # past argument or value
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Unrecognized option $key" # unknown option
    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done

# VALIDATION
if $UPLOAD; then
   if [ "$EDISON_DEVICE" = "" ]
   then
      echo 'Please use option --edison to compile project or fill default EDISON_DEVICE on script'
      exit
   fi
fi

# EXECUTION
if $CLEAN; then
   docker run --rm -it -v $WORK_DIR:/tmp --workdir /tmp inteliotdevkit/intel-iot-yocto -c "make clean"
fi

if $BUILD; then
   docker run --rm -it -v $WORK_DIR:/tmp --workdir /tmp inteliotdevkit/intel-iot-yocto -c "make"
fi

if $TEST; then
   docker run --rm -it -v $WORK_DIR:/tmp --workdir /tmp inteliotdevkit/intel-iot-yocto -c "make test"
fi

if $CREATE_DOC; then
   make docs
fi

if $UPLOAD; then
   echo -e "${COLOR}Copy program-test-python to Edison device${NC}"
   scp program-test/PythonConnectorEdison.py program-test/_PythonConnectorEdison.so program-test/python_script.py $EDISON_DEVICE
fi
```

Comment: I did it the same as you, for me it works. What is the content of your shell script?

Comment: I have added the script content

Comment: Once the script is revealed, possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536778/how-to-workaround-the-input-device-is-not-a-tty-when-using-grunt-shell-to-invo

Answer (score 0):

Your script is fine and works for me if I just echo all commands that should be executed. The problem is about the docker command. Remove the `-t` from your docker command, answer from [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40536892/8051589).

> The "-t" tells docker to configure the tty, which won't work if you don't have a tty and try to attach to the container (default when you don't do a "-d").

---

If you want to use the interactive mode and see output instead you can start an own shell that is reading the argument as command (`-c`) and is interactive (`-i`) by setting the following.

On the Main page set Location to:

```
/usr/bin/sh
```

On the Arguments add:

```
-ci "/home/lukasz/bitbucket/driver/compile_ubuntu.sh -c"
```

---

**Edit #1:**

As you wrote in your comment that it can still find no TTY consider [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/418557). If there is no `/etc/inittab` read [this answer on aksubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/34310):

> Just remove `/dev/console`
>
> ```
> cd /dev
> rm -f console
> ln -s ttyS0 console
> ```
>
> edit/change the `/etc/inittab` content
>
> ```
> ::askfirst:/bin/sh
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> ttyS0::askfirst:/bin/sh
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answer. After replacing `-it` with `-i` I indeed dont see the tty error, but I dont see any aoutput from docker as well.

Comment: @Bremen: What is when you also use `-a stderr -a stdout`?

Comment: Should I add those parameters when running docker?

Comment: Yes it is a docker run argument, see here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/.

Comment: I do `docker run --rm -i -a stderr -a stdout -v $WORK_DIR:/tmp --workdir /tmp inteliotdevkit/intel-iot-yocto -c "make clean"` and there is still no output in eclipse

Comment: @Bremen: I extended my answer. Then use your `-t` as before and report what happens.

Comment: I did the way you showed. I only changed `/usr/bin/sh` to `/bin/sh` as this is my location. The output now is `/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.`. In command line `/bin/sh -ci "/home/lukasz/bitbucket/driver/compile_ubuntu.sh -c"` works perfectly well

Comment: If you look under the Common tab in the External Tool Configuration is the checkbox: `Allocate console (necessary for input)` activated?

Comment: Yes, without it there is no output at all

Comment: @Bremen: Try this answer it seems something wrong with your terminal under ubuntu: https://superuser.com/a/418557. After this both variants should work, with own shell and without.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The problem with that config is that I wount be able to run processes in the background by using `ctrl+Z` like one of the users specified. Are there any more local solutions?

Comment: @Bremen: I think that's your state now that you can't do that because you haven't a tty. If you change that as in the answer then docker will work in eclipse with that tty and you can do such things as `bg`, `ctrl+z` and so on.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. But I do not have `/etc/inittab` file, should I create it if it doesnt exist?

Comment: @Bremen: No if this file is not there the configurations files are in `/etc/init` like it's said here: https://askubuntu.com/a/34310

Comment: But which file exacly in `/etc/init`?

Comment: @Bremen: Sorry I have no Ubuntu installed here, just CentOS... You have to find it out for yourself googling a bit.

Comment: I did a `sudo grep -r "*askfirst*" ./` in the `/etc/init` but such string does not exist.