# stdin is not a tty with Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have Jenkins installed locally on my laptop running windows 10. I spin up a Linux container running SQL Server, however when I attempt to run the following:

```
 winpty docker exec -it SQLLinuxnull sudo /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P P@ssword1 -Q 'EXEC sp_configure '\''clr enabled'\'', 1;'
```

I get:

```
stdin is not a tty
```

When I run the `docker exec` command from a powershell session it completes without any issues. Trawling this site pulls up answer suggesting that this might be something to do with whatever account is being used in the Linux container requiring the ability to execute sudo and that I should alter the `/etc/sudoers` file, the problem being is that I do not have an `/etc/sudoers` file, according to `uname -a` this is the version of Linux the container is based on (not that its base is the official Microsoft SQL server in Linux image):

```
# uname -a
Linux f9509a952eae 4.9.49-moby #1 SMP Wed Sep 27 00:36:29 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Can someone confirm that this is a sudoers related issue.

Comment: I believe `docker -it` expects a TTY, so no, this *isn't* necessarily a sudoers issue. Though you should be able to stop using the `-it` arguments to `docker` (assuming that the `sudo` invocation is passwordless) if you configured your `sudoers` to not have the `RequireTTY` flag set.

Comment: (That said, if you didn't have a `/etc/sudoers` visible from the relevant namespace then `sudo` wouldn't work, so that's obviously incorrect. That said, the Linux kernel version has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the userspace tools, so the provided kernel release tells us nothing about the `sudo` installation).

Comment: (...note "visible from the relevant namespace" -- ie. we care about whether there's an `/etc/sudoers` *inside the Docker container*, not inside the Linux install that's hosting Docker).

Comment: Do you need `sudo` for that command?  It's the `requiretty` option in the sudo config

Comment: @Matt, ...however, if `sudo` were failing because RequireTTY isn't set, that's a different message. So I'm pretty sure `docker` is failing before it gets to invoking `sudo`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Ah ok, but if not sudo it could be shell initialisation either before or after sudo. `docker exec` has run and moved into the Linux VM space for a `stdin is not a tty` message to appear.  The command might even work without the `-it` as then there won't be a psuedo tty for whatever is trying to use it.

Comment: I have no idea what `winpty` adds into the mix though

Comment: @CharlesDuffy removing the -it did the trick, if you reply to the thread I will mark your response as the answer and upvote it.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43099116/596285 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/40536778/596285

Answer (score 3):

```
docker exec -it
```

...requires that it be run in a context with a TTY available. If you can avoid needing stdin or a terminal later in the program's execution (for example, having `/etc/sudoers` *inside the container* configured with the `RequireTTY` option disabled), you should be able to simply remove the `-it` flags.